# How can I do this by using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I'm trying to compare `pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table()` and `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`. I have an classic data-set about tips:

```
import pandas as pd  
url = 'https://raw.github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/tips.csv'  
tips = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Now, I want to aggregate only tip_pct and size, and additionally group by day. I’ll put smoker in the table columns and day in the rows. By using `pivot_table` I can do that:

```
tips.pivot_table(['tip_pct', 'size'], index=['sex', 'day'], columns='smoker')
```

But now how can I do this task with `groupby`? I've tried but the results were not as expected:

```
tips.groupby(['sex', 'day'])['tip_pct', 'size'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a problem with your column names.  In your example you are using `tip_pct`.  The column in the data set is called `tip`.  `pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table()` happily ignores this missing column, while `pandas.DataFrame.groupby()` complains.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd  
url = 'https://raw.github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/master/pandas/tests/data/tips.csv'  
tips = pd.read_csv(url)

print(tips.groupby(['sex', 'day', 'smoker'])['tip', 'size'].mean())
```

**Results:**

```
                         tip      size
sex    day  smoker                    
Female Fri  No      3.125000  2.500000
            Yes     2.682857  2.000000
       Sat  No      2.724615  2.307692
            Yes     2.868667  2.200000
       Sun  No      3.329286  3.071429
            Yes     3.500000  2.500000
       Thur No      2.459600  2.480000
            Yes     2.990000  2.428571
Male   Fri  No      2.500000  2.000000
            Yes     2.741250  2.125000
       Sat  No      3.256563  2.656250
            Yes     2.879259  2.629630
       Sun  No      3.115349  2.883721
            Yes     3.521333  2.600000
       Thur No      2.941500  2.500000
            Yes     3.058000  2.300000
```